# What is the most efficent way to convert a QStringView to a std::string?

Tags: c++, qt, c++20, stdstring, qt6

I have a function that gets an argument as `QStringView`. Among other things, this must be converted into a `std::string`. `QString` has the function `toStdString()` for this. Is there a way to avoid the potentially expensive intermediate step via `QString`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting between character encodings is hard to get right.  QString stores 16 bit UTF-16.  `toStdString` reencodes this as utf-8 using an intermediate byte array using `toUtf8`.

`QStringView` also has `toUtf8` that returns a `QByteArray` and has the same guarantees as `QString`.

```
std::string toStdString( QStringView view ) {
  auto bytes = view.toUtf8(); // allocates and converts.
  return {bytes.constData(), bytes.length()}; // copies to a std::string
}
```

this drops 1 memory copy compared to the naive

```
std::string toStdString( QStringView view ) {
  return QString(view).toStdString();
}
```

there is 1 intermediate memory copy that can, in theory, be removed as well; you could directly convert from UTF16 QStringView data to a buffer in a `std::string`.

```
std::string toStdString( QStringView view ) {
  auto toUtf8 = QStringEncoder(QStringEncoder::Utf8);
  auto space = toUtf8.requiredSpace(view.length());
  std::string retval;
  // make a string of all nulls:
  retval.resize(space+1); // +1 probably not needed
  // Ideally use C++23's `resize_and_overwrite`
  // instead of `resize` above.  Without that, on large (>1k)
  // strings other solutions are faster.

  // output the UTF8 into the std::string:
  char* end = toUtf8.appendToBuffer(retval.data(), view);
  // Strip the nulls logically from the returned string:
  retval.resize(end-retval.data());
  return retval;
}
```

this is an attempt to avoid that intermediate buffer allocation.  It may be incorrect and have bugs, but the design is sound.

In theory an even crazier system that works out the actual space required for the UTF16 before (or as you) make the output buffer could be possible.

(resize_and_overwrite optimization added because of @BenjaminBuch excellent analysis in another answer).

Answer (score 4):

**This is an addition to the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943188/17726418) from user [Yakk - Adam Nevraumont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk-adam-nevraumont).**

I have checked by `unittest` that the conversions are all equivalent. Then I wrote (***google benchmark***) benchmarks for the different methods. I would like to share the results here.

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringView>
#include <QStringEncoder>

std::string qStringToStdString(QString const& data) {
    return data.toStdString();
}

std::string qStringViewToStdString1(QStringView const data) {
    return data.toString().toStdString();
}

std::string qStringViewToStdString2(QStringView const data) {
    auto const bytes = data.toUtf8();
    return std::string(bytes.constData(), bytes.length());
}

std::string qStringViewToStdString3(QStringView const data) {
    auto toUtf8 = QStringEncoder(QStringEncoder::Utf8);
    auto len = toUtf8.requiredSpace(data.length());
    std::string result;
#ifdef __cpp_lib_string_resize_and_overwrite
    result.resize_and_overwrite(len, [len](char*, std::size_t) { return len; });
#else
    result.resize(len);
#endif
    char* end = toUtf8.appendToBuffer(result.data(), data);
    result.resize(end - result.data());
    return result;
}

static void qt_to_std(benchmark::State& state) {
    QString test(state.range(0) - 1, 'A');
    for (auto _ : state) {
        auto str = cadapt::qt_to_std<char>(test);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(str);
    }
}

static void qt_view_to_std_1(benchmark::State& state) {
    QString data(state.range(0) - 1, 'A');
    QStringView test(data);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        auto str = qStringViewToStdString1(test);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(str);
    }
}

static void qt_view_to_std_2(benchmark::State& state) {
    QString data(state.range(0) - 1, 'A');
    QStringView test(data);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        auto str = qStringViewToStdString2(test);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(str);
    }
}

static void qt_view_to_std_3(benchmark::State& state) {
    QString data(state.range(0) - 1, 'A');
    QStringView test(data);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        auto str = qStringViewToStdString3(test);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(str);
    }
}

BENCHMARK(qt_to_std)
    ->Arg(4)->Arg(6)->Arg(8)->Arg(10)->Arg(12)->Arg(16)
    ->Arg(20)->Arg(32)->Arg(64)->Arg(128)->Arg(256)
    ->Arg(512)->Arg(1024)->Arg(2048)->Arg(4096)
    ->Arg(8192)->Arg(16384)->Arg(32768)->Arg(65536);

BENCHMARK(qt_view_to_std_1)
    ->Arg(4)->Arg(6)->Arg(8)->Arg(10)->Arg(12)->Arg(16)
    ->Arg(20)->Arg(32)->Arg(64)->Arg(128)->Arg(256)
    ->Arg(512)->Arg(1024)->Arg(2048)->Arg(4096)
    ->Arg(8192)->Arg(16384)->Arg(32768)->Arg(65536);

BENCHMARK(qt_view_to_std_2)
    ->Arg(4)->Arg(6)->Arg(8)->Arg(10)->Arg(12)->Arg(16)
    ->Arg(20)->Arg(32)->Arg(64)->Arg(128)->Arg(256)
    ->Arg(512)->Arg(1024)->Arg(2048)->Arg(4096)
    ->Arg(8192)->Arg(16384)->Arg(32768)->Arg(65536);

BENCHMARK(qt_view_to_std_3)
    ->Arg(4)->Arg(6)->Arg(8)->Arg(10)->Arg(12)->Arg(16)
    ->Arg(20)->Arg(32)->Arg(64)->Arg(128)->Arg(256)
    ->Arg(512)->Arg(1024)->Arg(2048)->Arg(4096)
    ->Arg(8192)->Arg(16384)->Arg(32768)->Arg(65536);
```

```
QStringView=>QString.toStdString  => qt_view_to_std_1
QStringView=>QStringEncoder/C++20 => qt_view_to_std_3 (resize)
QString.toStdString               => qt_to_std
QStringView=>toUtf8               => qt_view_to_std_2
QStringView=>QStringEncoder/C++23 => qt_view_to_std_3 (resize_and_overwrite)
```

```
Length  qt_view_to_std_1  qt_view_to_std_3  qt_to_std  qt_view_to_std_2  qt_view_to_std_3
                                     C++20                                          C++23
     4             79 ns             15 ns      42 ns             35 ns             11 ns
     6             79 ns             30 ns      44 ns             36 ns             28 ns
     8             80 ns             31 ns      50 ns             37 ns             29 ns
    10             81 ns             32 ns      40 ns             38 ns             31 ns
    12             82 ns             34 ns      40 ns             39 ns             32 ns
    16             84 ns             37 ns      48 ns             41 ns             36 ns
    20            104 ns             28 ns      54 ns             49 ns             27 ns
    32            110 ns             38 ns      62 ns             55 ns             37 ns
    64            110 ns             40 ns      62 ns             57 ns             39 ns
   128            117 ns             44 ns      67 ns             63 ns             42 ns
   256            128 ns             53 ns      73 ns             69 ns             49 ns
   512            193 ns             85 ns     105 ns            113 ns             83 ns
  1024            232 ns            134 ns     137 ns            146 ns            113 ns
  2048            339 ns            229 ns     232 ns            239 ns            182 ns
  4096            516 ns            412 ns     374 ns            379 ns            302 ns
  8192           1504 ns            853 ns     762 ns            729 ns            549 ns
 16384           2317 ns           1807 ns    1602 ns           1571 ns           1134 ns
 32768          25243 ns           3816 ns    3148 ns           3082 ns           2223 ns
 65536          70484 ns           7869 ns    6987 ns           6465 ns           4512 ns
```

(Smaller is better)

[image: logarithmic scale]

The conversion from `QStringView` via `QString` to `std::string` is by far the slowest. Especially for large strings it is a complete order of magnitude (factor 10) slower than `QString` to `std::string`.

The method via `QStringEncoder` performs best, but only if it uses the ***C++23*** optimization via `resize_and_overwrite`. Thereby the memory is not initialized during resize. In ***C++20*** mode it is filled with zeros, which eats a lot of time with large strings.

[image: linear scale big strings]

For small string sizes there is no significant difference between ***C++20*** `resize` and ***C++23*** `resize_and_overwrite`.

[image: linear scale small strings]

Comment: The biggest surprise I get here is that my `QStringEncoder` implementation was correct.

Comment: `resize_and_overwrite` optimization note added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Premature optimization is one of the worst ideas. Just go in front of a deep copy of `QString` and then convert to the `std::string`.

However, if for some reason you want to bother with it, you have a few options.

It makes sense to switch to `toWCharArray` or change the encoding with `toUtf8`. Option without any copy its just take raw data by `.utf16()` from `QStringView` and create `std::u16string_view` from this pointer.